# Form validation failed in django

Tags: python, django

I have a simple form

forms.py

```
class CraveDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = crave_data
        exclude=['date']

class CraveReplyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = comments
        exclude=['date', 'crave']
```

model.py

```
class crave_data(models.Model):
    #person = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post=models.TextField(blank = True,null = True)
    date= models.DateTimeField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.post

class comments(models.Model):

    crave=models.OneToOneField(crave_data)
    reply=models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank = True,null = True)
    date= models.DateTimeField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.reply
```

and views.py

```
def crave_view(request):
    if (request.method=="POST"):
        form1=CraveDataForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form1.is_valid():
            crave_made = form1.save(commit=False)
            crave_made.person = request.user
            crave_made.save()  
            messages.success(request, 'You Registered Successfully')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please enter all required fields')
    else:                    
        form1=CraveDataForm()
    return render(request, "crave/crave.html", { 'form1' : form1 })

def comment_view(request):
    if (request.method=="POST"):
        form2 = CraveReplyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form2.is_valid():
            reply = form2.save(commit=False)
            reply.person=request.user
            #reply.crave = request.user
            reply.save()
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please enter all required fields')

    else:                    
        form2 = CraveReplyForm()



    return render(request, "crave/comment.html", { 'form2' : form2 })
```

my template fie crave.html

```
<form class="horizontal-form" role="form" action="/crave/" method="post"  style="padding: 10px;">
           {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group" >


                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                        {{ form1.post.label_tag }}{{ form1.post }} <br /><br>   
                        </div>
                        </div>      
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="crave" />
                    </form>

                    <form action="/crave/reply_get/">
                    <input type="submit">
        </form>
```

my comment.html

```
<form class="horizontal-form" role="form" action="/crave/reply_get/" method="post"  style="padding: 10px;">
           {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group" >
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                        {{ form2.reply.label_tag }} {{ form2.reply }}   </br> </br>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="reply" />
        </form>
```

when i click on crave button i want to save data for form one only without saving data for second form. So comments will be for related posts only. Using foreign key. But i am getting the error here in "reply.crave = crave_made" i want to access the crave made from create_view view.
Help me.

Comment: for starters, `date` is a required field. So, whn you do `.save(commit=False)`, you might want to assign today's date

Comment: What is `UserCreationForm`?

Comment: Hay bymistake i put UserCreationForm there.,,,,,,,,, I edited now,,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your forms are derived from `UserCreationForm` so fields of that form should also be present to make it valid.

But I think you want to inherit from `ModelForm` and not `UserCreationForm`.

So change your code as

```
class CraveDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = crave_data
        exclude=['date']

class CraveReplyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = comments
        exclude=['date', 'crave']
```

Comment: Hay still i am getting the same error,,,,,,,,,,, Is that a reasone that i am not feeling all the data of form like username, password, confirm password,,,, i just dont want that fields thats why i am not included that fields,,,,,,,, reply me please

Comment: @user3541454, I'm not sure you will get same error with modified code. If there are no fields in the data that form requires, you will get _required field error_. However, that not the only error in `form.is_valid()`. Try to show all errors in the form and see why its not valid.

Comment: reply = form2.save(commit=False)
            reply.person=request.user
            reply.crave = crave_made
            reply.save()
but crave made is another view. How to access the crave_made from another view